# GNU Mailutils: How to encode a '*' in a password

Tags: urlencode

I am trying to access a remote mailbox using mailutils message command. The password contains a '*' character. No matter whether I use this character straight or percent encoded I always get an authentication error.

Contents of mailutils-test.cfg

```
mailbox {
  mailbox-pattern "imap://userjoe:secret*pwd@imap.mydomain.de/INBOX";
}
```

or

```
mailbox {
  mailbox-pattern "imap://userjoe:secret%2Apwd@imap.mydomain.de/INBOX";
}
```

Command used from a linux bash

```
messages --config-file=/srv/www/htdocs/mailutils-test.cfg --config-verbose --debug-level=auth.trace9
```

How can I fix this? I read the doc but could not find any advice on this problem.